# Issue with setting $PATH directories

Tags: macos, bash, environment-variables

For some strange reason, I'm getting a "No such file or directory" error for my `$PATH` variable. I have tried to edit my path using `export`, changing it from what it was originally to every permutation from a single directory path to the original.

When there is one directory (e.g., `export PATH=/bin`), I get "/bin: Is a Directory". But once I add more than one directory (e.g., `export PATH=/bin:/sbin`), I get "No such file or directory".

I'm curious to see what the cause of this issue is!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RE; your comment:

`/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/u‌sr/local/mysql/bin: No such file or directory` will be generated if you have a line which says:

```
$PATH
```

maybe on its own, or maybe you have `$PATH=...`.  That is, the shell is trying to execute a program named:

`/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/u‌sr/local/mysql/bin`

Lose the $ on the left-hand side.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you *are* using the `export` variant. You almost certainly have spaces in there and you shouldn't, as per the following transcript:

```
pax> PATH= /bin
bash: /bin: is a directory

pax> PATH= /bin/sbin
bash: /bin/sbin: No such file or directory
```

The first is caused because you're setting the path temporarily to an empty string while attempting to run that directory. That's because you can do things like:

```
pax> xyzzy=1

pax> echo $xyzzy
1

pax> xyzzy=2 bash -c 'echo $xyzzy'
2

pax> echo $xyzzy
1
```

In other words, it's a way of changing an environment variable for a single command, and having it automatically revert when the command is finished.

The second case is simply because there *is* no `/bin/sbin` directory. So it detects that *before* it complains about the fact that you're trying to run a directory.

Setting a variable in `bash` is a no-space thing (unless you have spaces in your directory names, in which case they should be quoted). In addition, they need to be colon-sparated. Hence you're looking for things like:

```
PATH=/bin
PATH=/bin:/sbin
PATH="/bin:/sbin:/directory with spaces in it:$HOME/bin"
```

Comment: whoops, the second issue bin/sbin was an error on my part when writing the question my actual export is correct (I think!) here is the content of $PATH `/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin: No such file or directory`
I am also aware that it is a no space operation but the issue might come from. $PATH is also edited by editing the .bash_profile

Answer (score 0):

The `export` function will only change the variable for the current terminal session.

Write your `PATH` inside `~/.bash_profile` if you want to change it permanently.

For this modification to work you have to close your current terminal and reopen it.